# How can I make a copy of a tuple containing nested tuples in Python?

Tags: python, tuples

I'm working on a question that requires me to define a function `copy_tree` that takes an argument `tree` (tuple that may contain tuples) and return a copy of the tree (ie. stored in a different memory location).

My current code is:

```
def copy_tree(tree):
    new_tree = ()
    for i in tree:
        new_i = (i,) + ()
        new_tree = new_tree + new_i
    return new_tree
```

However, this does not work for the nested tuples, as the tuples inside are not "copied" but rather referred to.

e.g. if I run

```
a = ((3, 2), 1, (4,), 5)
b = copy_tree(a)
print(a[0] is b[0])
```

the output has to be `False`.

How do I make the tuples copies?

Edit: I am *not allowed* to use the `deepcopy` module.

Comment: Are you aware of the ``copy`` module?

Comment: your code does not run. `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'`

Comment: You can use `copy.deepcopy` or `tuple(map(tuple, tree))` if all are tuples, but why do you want to copy the tuples at all? Tuples are immutable.

Comment: you need to do `a[0]==b[0]`, i think, to compare the values. Here is more on that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python

Comment: @hadik that wouldn't work in this case, since a copied value will still compare equal to itself even if it's in a different memory address.

Comment: In fact, even `copy.deepcopy` will _not_ create a copy of the tuples (`is` same returns `True`) because it makes no real sense.

Comment: @hadik @roganjosh yeah, the question specifically wants me to write the code such that using the `is` operator will return `False`. No issue if `==` returns `True`.

Comment: I mostly agree with what tobias said. One of the benefits of using immutable objects is that it's safe for them to share references. OTOH, a tuple _can_ contain mutable objects, so this deep-copying operation isn't totally useless. ;)

Comment: @rocksportrocker you are right. Sorry, I copied the wrong code. Updated it with my latest code which runs and produces a visually correct result but does not pass the `is` test.

Comment: @PM2Ring Right, but since OP's code does neither create copies of the inner objects nor attempty to work recursively I assumed this not to be the case.

Comment: @tobias_k tuples are not completely immutable if their contents are immutable. eg. `([1], [2])`. If you wanted a deep copy of that tuple you would need to copy both it and its contents.

Comment: @RyanChng it does pass the test on my computer, which python version are you using?

Comment: @Dunes I am aware of that, but OP explicitly only attempty to copy the tuples, not their contents. See my above comment.

Comment: @toti08 it passes that test on mine too, but fails a bunch of private tests on the autograder website I use. I think the private cases involve more layers of nesting.

Comment: So you should write a recursive test function that compares two trees, applying the `is` test at every level. That way you can guarantee that `copy_tree` behaves correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing the recursive step - you only copy the top-level tuple.

```
def copy_tree(tree):
  new_tree = ()
  for i in tree:
    # i is not copied
    new_i = (i,) + ()
    new_tree = new_tree + new_i
  return new_tree
```

Adding recursion produces copies of *every* layer of the tree. Note that you may copy *only* tuples:

```
def copy_tree(tree):
  new_tree = ()
  for i in tree:
    # recursively copy i *if it is a tuple*
    if isinstance(i, tuple):
      new_i = (copy_tree(i),)
    else:
      new_i = (i,)
    new_tree = new_tree + new_i
  return new_tree
```

---

Recursion fixes the result, but the approach you have taken is inefficient - there are many transient tuples created and thrown away. Every time a tuple is "extended" via `+`, the old one is thrown away and a new one created.

A first step is to delay creation of the tuple until all children are converted:

```
def copy_tree(tree):
    children = []
    for child in tree:
        # we *always* preserve a child, so ternary if expresses this better
        child = copy_tree(child) if isinstance(child, tuple) else child
        children.append(child)
    # create a new tuple including all children
    return tuple(children)
```

Since that list only exists to be turned into a tuple, we can get rid of that as well: a generator expression allows to feed the converted children directly to the `tuple` constructor.

```
def copy_tree(tree):
    # generator expression - only run when consumed by tuple later on
    children = (
        copy_tree(child) if isinstance(child, tuple) else child
        for child in tree
    )
    return tuple(children)
```

Of course, you can also directly put the generator expression inside the `tuple`.

Comment: This actually worked, thanks! I haven't learned isinstance yet, but I substituted that line with `if type(i) == tuple`. I'm still learning at an introductory level, so I don't think they are looking for the following solutions you posted - but the first one aids in my understanding well. Thanks so much!

Comment: @RyanChng `isinstance` is generally preferred over `type` for this sort of thing. It doesn't matter here, but `isinstance` is more flexible, since it can test multiple types in one go, and `isinstance(obj, cls)` will return True if `obj` is an instance of `cls` or any child class of `cls`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a recursive solution that deep copies (nested) tuples, leaves other objects unchanged, and doesn't use the `copy` module:

```
def copy_tree(tree):
    if isinstance(tree, tuple):
        return tuple(map(copy_tree, tree))
        # or, maybe more readable
        # return tuple(copy_tree(x) for x in tree)
    return tree
```

Recursion is definitely the most elegant approach if you do not know nesting levels in advance.

Comment: The use of `map` function for recursive call is very clever. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Simply passing an existing tuple to the `tuple` constructor will not create a new copy of the constructor. Instead, you should pass an equivalent list to the `tuple` constructor to make a copy of a tuple:

```
def copy_tuple(t):
    output = []
    for i in t:
        if isinstance(i, tuple):
            output.append(copy_tuple(i))
        else:
            output.append(i)
    return tuple(output)
```

so that:

```
a = ((3, 2), 1, (4,), 5)
b = copy_tuple(a)
print(a)
print(b)
print(a[0] is b[0])
```

would output:

```
((3, 2), (4,), 5)
((3, 2), (4,), 5)
False
```

Comment: Converting to `list` is a clever "hack" to prevent `tuple` from just returning the input, but you might add _why_ tuple behaves like this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the intention of the question was to use some sort of recursion. The following code would deep copy the tree recursively.

```
def copy_tree(tree):
    new_tree = ()
    for node in tree:
        if type(node) == tuple:
            new_tree += (copy_tree(node),)
        else:
            new_tree += (node,)
    return new_tree


a = ((3, 2), 1, (4,), 5)
b = copy_tree(a)

print(a[0] is b[0])
```

and the last print would give you False.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple version that copies the tree by feeding the `tuple` constructor with a recursive generator. To test it, I've written another recursive function `compare_trees`, which you can use to check that corresponding tuples aren't identical (using `is`), and that corresponding inner items have the same value (using `==`).

```
def copy_tree(tree):
    return tuple(copy_tree(u) if isinstance(u, tuple) else u for u in tree)

def compare_trees(tree1, tree2, indent=''):
    print(indent, 'tree1', tree1, 'tree2', tree2, 'identical', tree1 is tree2)
    indent += '  '
    for u1, u2 in zip(tree1, tree2):
        if isinstance(u1, tuple) and isinstance(u2, tuple):
            compare_trees(u1, u2, indent)
        else:
            print(indent, 'item1', u1, 'item2', u2, 'equal', u1 == u2)

a = ((3, 2), 1, (4,), 5, (6, (7, 8)))
b = copy_tree(a)
print(b)
compare_trees(a, b)
```

**output**

```
((3, 2), 1, (4,), 5, (6, (7, 8)))
 tree1 ((3, 2), 1, (4,), 5, (6, (7, 8))) tree2 ((3, 2), 1, (4,), 5, (6, (7, 8))) identical False
   tree1 (3, 2) tree2 (3, 2) identical False
     item1 3 item2 3 equal True
     item1 2 item2 2 equal True
   item1 1 item2 1 equal True
   tree1 (4,) tree2 (4,) identical False
     item1 4 item2 4 equal True
   item1 5 item2 5 equal True
   tree1 (6, (7, 8)) tree2 (6, (7, 8)) identical False
     item1 6 item2 6 equal True
     tree1 (7, 8) tree2 (7, 8) identical False
       item1 7 item2 7 equal True
       item1 8 item2 8 equal True
```

I suppose that it's a little ironic that the test code is larger and more complex than the code we want to test, but sometimes that's inevitable. ;)

Answer (score -1):

You should use the [copy module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html).

This module has two functions to fit your needs, copy and deepcopy.
copy does the same than copy_tree.

For example if you do :

```
import copy
l = [[0],[0]]
l2 = copy.copy(l)
l[0] = [1]
l[1][0] = [1]
```

Then l2 will be [[0],[1]]
The first element of l2 has not changed because you replaced l first element. However, the second element has changed because you mutated the second element of l, which is a reference to the element of l2.

If you use deepcopy:

```
 import copy
 l = [[0],[0]]
 l2 = copy.deepcopy(l)
 l[0] = [1]
 l[1][0] = [1]
```

Then l2 will be [[0],[0]] because l and l2 does not share anything in common anymore.

Comment: Now make it work with tuples, as per the question. ;)